# configure your forms app unable to select iOS on target platform

Tags: xamarin.ios

Hi all new to this but just downloaded and installed xamarin studio to my mac but iOS on the target platforms: section on the configure your forms app page is greyed out and cant be selected

any idea how to solve this please

Comment: Provide a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The Xamarin studio don't install everything you need automatically.

1 - Install the latest iOS SDK.

2 - Install the latest version of Xcode.

3 - Install the Xamarin Studio.

Full Guide: 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/mac/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue `Visual Studio 7.2.2`, the iOS box was disabled. There were couple of issues I had

1. I had the Xcode app named as `XCode9.app` in the application folder so VS was unable to find the location, so I fixed that one.
2. I then searched for installed components `About VisualStudio--> ShowDetails` and found that `Xamarin.iOS10` was installed which seem to have incompatibility with `XCode9` so I ran the `VS installer` once again and found that `Xamarin.iOS11` was out and after installing the update and restarting, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

[Download](https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio-mac/?sku=communitymac&rel=16) the visual studio for mac again and run the installer. It will show you the missing components and give you a way to install them correctly. Worked for me here. It will check what is already installed, you won't have to install everything again.